# How to compare the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is a mysql question, and I do not even know if it is possible, but as you can see below, I have 2 tables. They are basically doing the same just with a difference. One has paid = 1 and the other has paid = 0

So my headaches are, if Table 2 have **cardid**, **price** and **title** precise as in Table 1 which includes paid = 1, it must not be displayed in table # 2. Oh, and comparison may only take place if **created** also matches, + - 5min is okay.

sql statement 1

```
SELECT t.cardid, ct.title, t.transactionid, FROM_UNIXTIME(t.created),t.priceafterdiscount, t.paid 
FROM transactions as t
left join exp_channel_titles ct on t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id
where t.paid = 0 
and t.transactiontime > '2013-09-23' and 
t.phoneid != '123456789012345' and 
t.cardid != '88888888' and 
t.restaurant_id NOT in (47505) 
ORDER BY t.created DESC;
```

My output for tabel 1.

```
Card_ID     Title               Trans_ID Created              price   Paid
10017039    Café Cici           15887   2013-09-26 11:04:49  75     0
10017039    Café Cici           15885   2013-09-26 11:03:08  100    0
10017039    Café Cici           15884   2013-09-26 11:02:33  15000  0
10166152    Viet-Nam Nam        15870   2013-09-25 20:51:44  28800  0
10030773    Restaurant Shezan   15866   2013-09-25 20:10:35  38175  0
10030773    Restaurant Shezan   15865   2013-09-25 20:09:41  50900  0
10030773    Restaurant Shezan   15864   2013-09-25 20:08:13  38175  0
```

sql statement 2

```
SELECT t.cardid, ct.title, t.transactionid, FROM_UNIXTIME(t.created), t.priceafterdiscount, t.paid
FROM transactions as t
left join exp_channel_titles ct on t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id
where t.paid = 1
and t.transactiontime > '2013-09-23' and 
t.phoneid != '123456789012345' and 
t.cardid != '88888888' and 
t.restaurant_id NOT in (47505) 
ORDER BY t.created DESC
```

My output for tabel 2.

```
Card_ID     Title               Trans_ID Created              price   Paid
10171120    Hjørnet             15889   2013-09-26 11:18:47  6750    1
10017039    Café Cici           15888   2013-09-26 11:06:24  75      1
10017039    Café Cici           15886   2013-09-26 11:04:14  75      1
10129289    Café ZugarBaby      15876   2013-09-25 21:44:34  15000   1
10082903    Café Katz           15862   2013-09-25 19:40:26  19040   1
10064767    Restaurant Fønix    15857   2013-09-25 17:58:53  14250   1
```

Comment: _“They are basically doing the same just with a difference. One has paid = 1 and the other has paid = 0”_ – why, oh why? Why is it not _one_ table, that has a paid status of either 0 or 1 for each record?

Comment: They are in the same table, as can be seen on the name (transacations) of the table. There are 2 sql statement, because they run on each html page.

Answer (score 0):

select * from table 1 where row is not in table 2 by your conditions:

```
select * from 
table1 
left join table2 
on table1.cardid=table2.cardid 
and table1.price=table2.price 
and table1.title=table2.title and 
timestampdiff(minute,table1.created, table2.created) between -5 and 5

where table2.cardid is null
```

alternatively, you can union all your two queries, group by cardid, price, title, and add the condition having count(*)=1 and paid=0 but it won'T work with 5minute timestamp condition

Comment: However, Table 1 and Table 2 (which is the same table) contains paid field, here is it variable, ranging from 0-1. I just split the table into 2 parts. So that the query contains one paid = 0 in where and the other contains the paid = 1 where

Comment: yes. table1 has the paid=0 records, table2 has the paid=1 records. query above should work as you wanted, to return paid=0 that is not found in the table with paid=1